# Cannot delete a record from database (SQL server)

Tags: vb.net

I managed to write this code in order to delete a record from a SQL Server database.

```
Private sub cmdDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click

    Dim strconnection As String = "Data Source=EASMAR-PC;Initial Catalog=DatabaseConnection;Integrated Security=True;"

    Dim _cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strconnection)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    _cn.Open()
    Try
        _DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(CInt(txtCurrent.Text) - 1).Delete()

        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim cmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        Dim DutyDetails As String = "SELECT ID from tblCustomer"

        adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(DutyDetails, _cn)
        adapter.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
        adapter.DeleteCommand = cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand

        Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)

        adapter.Update(_DataSet.Tables("0"))
End sub
```

Am I missing something?

I'm not getting any errors. but the record is still present.

Any help?

Than you :)

Comment: I don't think so. I checked :/

Comment: I can't see that you are actually calling the deleteCommand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub DeleteRecord(recordID As Integer)
    ' define connection string
    Dim connString As String = "Data Source=EASMAR-PC;Initial Catalog=DatabaseConnection;Integrated Security=True;"

    ' define SQL statement to execute, using a **PARAMETRIZED** query
    Dim deleteStmt As String = "DELETE FROM dbo.tblCustomer WHERE CustomerID = @ID"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(deleteStmt, conn)
            ' define parameter
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = recordID

            ' open connection, execute DELETE, close connection
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```